# destroy gtkmm message dialog?

Tags: c++, messagebox, gtkmm

I am using gtkmm 3.0.1 and I do not see an option when creating a `Gtk::MessageDialog` object to destroy the dialog after the user has clicked a button. The only way I found out to destroy a message dialog is to call it in a secondary function, but I feel that this has the possibility of being avoided. The documentation mentions no method of destroying it, only mentions that it is up to the user to destroy it.

Here's my code:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);
    Gtk::Window client;

    Gtk::MessageDialog dialog("Info", false, Gtk::MESSAGE_QUESTION, Gtk::BUTTONS_YES_NO);
    dialog.set_secondary_text( "Dialog");
    dialog.set_default_response(Gtk::RESPONSE_YES);
    dialog.run();

    cout << "dialog is still open, needs to be destroyed at this point." << endl;

    Gtk::Main::run(client);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: I guess: Since Gtk::Main::run(client) is not called, the dialog does not receive events.

Comment: what do you mean? `Gtk::Main::run(client);` is on the 2nd to last command.

Comment: ... after Gtk::MessageDialog

Comment: ..that just makes the dialog appear after the main window is exited by the user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you've created your `Gtk::MessageDialog` on the stack in `int main`.  Since that function won't exit until your program does your `MessageDialog` hangs around.

Few options:

1.) [Hide the dialog](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a285c1775842292ae4bc6d074aa892c61) when done with it, it'll be destroyed when int main exits.

2.) New it then delete it.

```
Gtk::MessageDialog* dialog = new Gtk::MessageDialog("Info", false, Gtk::MESSAGE_QUESTION, Gtk::BUTTONS_YES_NO);
dialog->set_secondary_text( "Dialog");
dialog->set_default_response(Gtk::RESPONSE_YES);
dialog->run();
delete dialog;
```

3.) Create it in it's own function or block so it'll be destroyed when that scope exits.

```
void showDialog() {
    Gtk::MessageDialog dialog("Info", false, Gtk::MESSAGE_QUESTION, Gtk::BUTTONS_YES_NO);
    dialog.set_secondary_text( "Dialog");
    dialog.set_default_response(Gtk::RESPONSE_YES);
    dialog.run();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    etc...
    showDialog();
    Gtk::Main::run(client);
    etc...
}
```

Comment: I noticed that there's in the documentation a line that says `virtual Gtk::MessageDialog::~MessageDialog() [virtual]` but I'm not quite sure how to use it, if that's what will deconstruct the dialog class.

Comment: Actually I was able to destroy it by just using `dialog.~MessageDialog();`.

Comment: Be careful with that approach.  While it will probably work, calling a destructor manually on a local variable can cause trouble: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/dont-call-dtor-on-local.html.